# Pound sign in javascript code changed to question symbol at run time

Tags: javascript

I am putting the pound symbol in a javascript array, but when I run the code it changes to question symbol.

Due to this change my code is not behaving correctly for pound symbol check.
Thanks !!

```
function containIllegalCharsInNotes(sInString) {

    // allowed set of special characters £
    var allowedSpecialCharacters = ['!', '@', '#', '£', '$', '%', '*', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', ':', ';', ',', '.', '\'', '?', '+', '-', ' '];

    var strWithoutAllowedCharacters = sInString;

    // remove allowed set of characters from input string
    for (var i = 0; i < allowedSpecialCharacters.length; i++) {
        while (strWithoutAllowedCharacters.indexOf(allowedSpecialCharacters[i]) > -1) {
            strWithoutAllowedCharacters = strWithoutAllowedCharacters.replace(allowedSpecialCharacters[i], '');
        }
    }

    // after removing allowed characters from string, check if remaining string is an alphanumeric string
    var isAlphaNumeric = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$").test(strWithoutAllowedCharacters);

    return isAlphaNumeric;
 }
```

Comment: Save the file as utf-8 without bom

Comment: I have a js file, where I had written that code. how can I save this JS file as utf-8. I am using visual studio 2015 for code editing.

Comment: @chandan
Short version: edit one file, select File -> Advanced Save Options. Instead of changing UTF-8 to Ascii, change it to UTF-8. Edit: Make sure you select the option that says no byte-order-marker (BOM)

Comment: Or using simple plain old Notepad.exe: load the file, choose Save As... then select UTF-8 under Encoding: and press Save, overwrite the existing file.

Answer (score 0):

you can read pound symbol from it ascii value at runtime as -

```
function containIllegalCharsInNotes(sInString) {
// replace carriage return
sInString = RemoveEnter(sInString);

var poundSymbol = String.fromCharCode(163); // fetching pound symbol from ascii value. As the code is rendering wrong character at runtime for pound symbol

// allowed set of special characters £
var allowedSpecialCharacters = ['!', '@', '#', poundSymbol, '$', '%', '*', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', ':', ';', ',', '.', '\'', '?', '+', '-', ' '];

var strWithoutAllowedCharacters = sInString;

// remove allowed set of characters from input string
for (var i = 0; i < allowedSpecialCharacters.length; i++) {
    while (strWithoutAllowedCharacters.indexOf(allowedSpecialCharacters[i]) > -1) {
        strWithoutAllowedCharacters = strWithoutAllowedCharacters.replace(allowedSpecialCharacters[i], '');
    }
}

// after removing allowed characters from string, check if remaining string is an alphanumeric string
var isAlphaNumeric = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$").test(strWithoutAllowedCharacters);

return isAlphaNumeric == false;
```

}